# What does a Space radiator/cooler look like exactly?

Tags: thermal-radiation, electronics, satellites

I understand the principles of radiating heat to space using heat pipes and whatnot but what exactly do these devices look like in real world applications? The closest example for a space base application is the electra deployable cooling radiator.

[image]

But this is covered in second surface mirrors and I cannot really find a COTS example or product to cool electronics like the Nvidia Jetson. I am familiar with Kerbal space program but those coolers are depicted like car radiators which may work but are probably just an artist depiction/interpretation. Is it truly as simple as adding a surface coating and protect it from the sun? Or a large surface reflective surface area? I imagine there is a network of heatpipes bonded to the inside surface of these second surface mirrors? I am trying to design a cooler for electronics serving in a LEO application just to provide some context here.

Comment: The active radiator surface is "dark" for in the relevant IR bands and as reflective as possible for solar radiation. Since the radiator has a black body temperature of approx. 320K, its spectral peak wavelength is roughly twenty times longer than the peak of the sun's radiation (so it's in the 10um range).

Comment: Closed because it's about engineering? My answer was about physics applied to physics research. This fundamental to physics, much more so than the mere mathematics that so many physicists limit themselves to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a picture of the [HETE-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HETE_2) spacecraft in test at MIT's Lincoln Laboratory.[image]

The silver areas are the parts we wanted to keep cool: they are covered with silver-teflon tape. The silver has low emissivity at optical wavelengths, so it reflects sunlight. The teflon has high emissivity in the thermal infrared, so it radiates heat. Most of the rest of what you see is gold: it absorbs some visible light, but it has very low infrared emissivity. We used it where we wanted to retain the heat. The light gold is gold-plated aluminum structure, while the dark gold is plastic thermal blanket with gold coating.

There are no heat pipes: those are only needed if the heat can't be adequately delivered to the radiating surface via the metal structure of the spacecraft.

Comment: If I could vote I would give you one but apparently I cant vote on the answers to my own question but thanks, this is at least something go off of.

Comment: Hi @XiJinpingOfficial and welcome to Physics SE! New users have to accumulate 15 reputation before they can upvote posts. (You're almost there already). In the meantime, you can "accept" one answer to your own question using the check mark next to the answer.